# Changing Splash Screen Dynamically

Tags: java, windows, image, splash-screen

I have an application (Java, Windows) that when opened, shows a splash screen (Good, right?). I want to know how I could change it each time the application loads (or set it to load from a location outside the app cuz I could change that). I'm using netbeans if that helps. Also, this application gets installed to their program files directory. Ideally, I would like to be able to load from %AppData%. I can't seem to figure out this part though! Thanks!

UPDATE*
Here is my folder structure and some more info!
[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: How is the splash screen currently made? Is there some code involved? Can you show it to us?

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of splash screens that you want to rotate through? Or do you want the user to be able to change the splash screen?

Comment: My program pulls data from our server and I write it to an image file. I want for it to select that file if possible